# Cordova 3.4.1 and calabash-ios

Tags: ios, cordova, calabash

I'm trying to get Calabash to work with an existing Cordova project. I have followed the instructions on calabash-io, both manual and automatic. I can confirm that the manual setup has resulted in the Calabash server running. But running the cucumber tells me that it can't find the .app file, I manually entered the .app, and all it does is loop "xcode-select: Error: unknown command option '-p'." several times and then stops "Unable to start. Make sure you've set APP_BUNDLE_PATH to a build supported by this simulator version
  Calabash::Cucumber::Launcher::StartError: Time out waiting for UIAutomation run-loop to Start."

Comment: If you build your app using Xcode and if it is in the default path calabash automatically detects the .app . If you build you app to a specific location using terminal xcode command you need to specify the  APP_BUNDLE_PATH in features/support/01_launch.rb file. like this

`APP_BUNDLE_PATH = "/Users/checkout/.jenkins/jobs/iPhoneApp_Calabash_Automated_Tests/workspace/ABCapp/build/Staging-iphonesimulator/ABCapp-cal.app"`

Answer (score 0):

On certain versions of MacOS Lion + Xcode, the `xcode-select` tool was missing the -p option.  This was causing ios-sim gem to raise an exception.

The solution is to upgrade to the most recent version of MacOS and Xcode.